# Write a function sum_integers(start, end) that takes two positive integers, start and end , and returns the sum of all integers

Tags: python

I am a beginner at python programming, and I am doing a question like this, the question is:

Write a function sum_integers(start, end) that takes two positive integers, start and end, and returns the sum of all integers comprised between start and end inclusive. The method should return `-1` if: `end < start; start < 0; end < 0`

I do not know how to start a question like this, if anyone can help me i will really be appreciated.The code is below:

```
def sum_integers(x,y):
    """return the sum of all integers comprised between start and end inclusive"""
    for value in range(x,y):
        value += 0
    return sum_integers(x,y)
```

Comment: You can check for -1 conditions with an if, then use the built-in function sum() and range() to get desired result. sum(range(start, end+1))

Comment: thank you so much, but why should there be y+1?

Comment: range is not inclusive on the second parameter, so +1 will include end in the sum

Answer (score 1):

As @Sam mentioned, adding some `if` statements can do the checks. Also fix your sum loop.

```
def sum_integers(x,y):
    if x < 0 or y < 0 or y < x: 
        return -1  # invalid inputs
    """return the sum of all integers comprised between start and end inclusive"""
    total = 0  # start at zero
    for value in range(x,y+1):  # use y+1 so y is included
        total += value  # add to total
    return total
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def sum_integers(x,y):
    """return the sum of all integers comprised between start and end inclusive"""
    if x>y: #first validate the input
        return -1

    value = 0 #you need to define value before adding to it
    for i in range(x,y+1): #range(x,y) ends at y-1, if end is inclusive, add 1 to y 
        value += i
    return value # return the sum not the function
```

good luck

Comment: @sahasrara62 I didn't understand your comment

Answer (score 0):

Well, sum of integers from 0 to n has a known formula: `n(n+1)/2`.

So you can do:

```
def sum_integers(start, end):
    if end < start:
        return -1
    if 0 in (start, end):
        return -1
    return int(end*(end+1)/2-start*(start+1)/2)+start
```

Example:

```
>>> sum_integers(10,20)
165
```

This works without all the fuss of `range` and adding one-by-one ; but it calculates via floating-point arithmetic, that's why it needs a final conversion to `int` to return an integer. Also, it may exceed the maximum size of a float in Python for super big integers. Indeed, Python integers have no limit (except memory on the PC) since Python 3.

So, here is another solution that makes use of a `range` + `sum`:

```
def sum_integers(start, end):
    if end < start:
        return -1
    if 0 in (start, end):
        return -1
    return sum(range(start, end+1))
```

It is pretty efficient too, because `range` returns an iterator and not
the plain values in a list, and `sum` is the builtin Python function.